# Array method that combines 'uniq' and 'compact'

Tags: ruby

I am trying to find unique elements in an array and remove the `nil` values from it. My solution looks like this:

```
@array = [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, nil, 5, nil, 5] 
@array.uniq.compact # => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is there any single method that does both the operations? If not, which is efficient, `@array.uniq.compact` or `@array.compact.uniq`?

Comment: No, there isn't. I guess `@array.compact.uniq` should be more efficient.

Comment: Nop. But create your own ;)

Comment: Using the bang counterparts (`@array.uniq!` / `@array.compact!`) to modify the array in-place should be more efficient.

Comment: Nah! we don't have :( , I have variety `(a | a).compact`. :p

Comment: You are not finding unique elements, you are extracting elements once for possibly duplicated elements.

Comment: I'd try benchmarking, although real world results may depend on the characteristics of your data - which is faster might depend on whether it is more likely that there be large numbers of duplicates or large numbers of nils.

Comment: If you are able to, use a `Set` instead of an `Array` so that duplicate values are never added.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, but you can append them in any order you like i.e.

```
array.uniq.compact
array.compact.uniq
```

As pointed out by phts, you can pass a block to `uniq` but I don't see that being a very helpful alternative over `uniq.compact`.

For better speed however, something like the following might help:

```
[].tap do |new_array|
  hash = {}
  original_array.each do |element|
    next if element.nil? || !hash[element].nil?
    new_array << (hash[element] = element)
  end
end
```

Finally, if speed isn't an issue and you'll be frequently using this method, then you could create your own method:

```
class Array
  def compact_uniq
    self.compact.uniq
  end

  def compact_blank # in case you want to remove all 'blanks' as well
    self.compact.reject(&:blank?)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

No there is no such method.

I think `@array.compact.uniq` and `@array.uniq.compact` are equal because both methods have O(N) complexity.

As @Stefan mentioned using methods with `!` may decries memory usage.

---

As an alternative way you may use only `uniq` method with a block which returns a surely existent element except `nil` so it will be skipped. For example

```
@array.uniq { |s| s.nil? ? @array.first : s }
```

But in this case you have to make sure that the first element of the array is not `nil`.

Comment: They both have O(n) time complexity. I'm curious: What about memory complexity?